# Bouncycastle PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator error in weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, weblogic

I'm trying to deploy a project to weblogic server. But I got an error like this;

```
    ####<Nov 22, 2017 3:30:23 PM EET> <Error> <Deployer> <nbia-pc> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1511357423637> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "456499572774374" for task "18". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator.<init>(Lorg/bouncycastle/crypto/Digest;)V"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator.<init>(Lorg/bouncycastle/crypto/Digest;)V
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
```

I used to this library for spring security, dependency version is 1.58

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.58</version>
        </dependency>
```

used class is that.

```
 @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
   auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).passwordEncoder(new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
```

where is the problem?

Comment: I have checked and no another. there is an interesting think in here. When I want to show SCryptPasswordEncoder() class it redirect me to spring-security library. But I'm getting bouncycastle error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bouncycastle/crypto/Digest class removed from bouncycastle library, so I have to change my encode algorithm.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.58</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

- SCryptPasswordEncoder uses bouncyCastle,
  https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/scrypt/SCryptPasswordEncoder.html
- you can see at pom which version is used http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-4.2.3.RELEASE.pom

(links are examples, I don't know your version of spring-security-crypto)

I think you should use same version of bouncy-castle as spring-security-crypto, or might you'll try to do this (not sure if this would work):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you, provided scope does not work, and I have no spring-security-crypto. My pom.xml updated above.

Comment: my spring version is 1.5.7.RELEASE